# is date is good candidate for clustred index key

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-administration, mssql-jdbc

i open one transaction and insert a row into table and close the ssms and reopen and check table but uncommitted transaction were in the resultset why this happen please tell me

Comment: Depends on what your data is.  If you only ever expect one record per day, ever, then sure.  But personally, I'd just stick with an int-based ID.

Comment: Show us your table definition if you want an answer that is more than just a guess.  Typically I do not like date columns for keys, but sometimes its the best option.

Comment: A quick google search turned up this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267326/how-to-choose-the-clustered-index-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

date can be a good primary key for clustered index, but in general scenario, we don't link many tables (foreign key) using date.

i think it is depend on your er-diagram.

Comment: no sir i am not connecting to any table i use date in where condition oftenly