# Best order of columns in clustered index

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, indexing

I'm looking to optimize a clustered index based on my where and order by clause.

```
where Active = 1 and Deleted = 0
order by ControlName
```

In my clustered index the order of my columns is Active, Deleted, and ControlName.

Can I optimize this further?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to choose the clustered index in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267326/how-to-choose-the-clustered-index-in-sql-server)

Comment: You optimize queries by introducing the appropriate indexes. You have only ONE clustered index and that choice must serve multiple purposes. If i had to guess, a filtered index (or indexed view) might be more useful since you seem to be looking for "current" rows and such queries are far more common in an active OLTP system.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't address the point I raised in my question.  I was looking to optimize a clustered index based on the contents of my where clause and order by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this query, the index you want is either `(Active, Deleted, ControlName)` or `(Deleted, Active, ControlName)`.

It does not have to be a clustered index.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I was thinking that, but not sure.  And I did try it with a non-clustered index and the optimizer chose the right index.